# What is this phenomenon called?

Tags: terminology, adaptation-comparison

Whenever I read a book, I create an image of how the character would look like, from the author's description, in my mind. And this image mostly would be different from person to person.

However, when I have watched the show or movie before reading the book, I tend to have the picture ready-made. So, even after reading the author's description of the character, the image from the show is the one which mostly lingers in the mind.

This is a very common phenomenon/experience for most of the readers. So, I was curious whether there is a name for it?

Comment: I can think of a term for the second phenomenon (film to book) but not for the first.